# flutter: Placing regular widgets on top of CustomPaint canvas

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, custom-painting

My app is mainly made up of CustomPainted pages. But I'd love to place one or two buttons such as `PopupMenuButton` or `IconButton` on top of the canvas.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. `CustomPaint` accepts a `child` property which can be used to place widgets on top of it, for example:

```dart
CustomPaint(
  painter: _RadialPainter(
    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    completedPercentage: progress.completed,
  ),
  child: Center(
    child: Text(
      '${progress.left}',
       style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
     ),
  ),
);
```

Take a note that the `_RadialPainter` extends the `CustomPainter`.